I made my first game in VR but when packaging
When I put in packing the following error appears:UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): ERROR: C:\Users\GAMER PC\Documents\Unreal Projects\VR\VR.uproject does not look like uproject file but no targets have been found! How do I solve this?
Chatgpt,youtube,reddit and settings in unreal
